# Passing sort order as a parameter

Tags: javascript, sql

Referring to the sample SQL statement below. I'm able to pass parameter values to the placeholder '?' in the statement. However I'm wondering whether it is possible to pass in the sort order in the same way?

So instead of this:

```
//Create SQL query
var getAccountsTransactionsStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement(
  "SELECT transactionId, fromAccount, toAccount, transactionDate, transactionAmount, transactionType " +
  "FROM accounttransactions " +
  "WHERE accounttransactions.fromAccount = ? OR accounttransactions.toAccount = ? " +
  "ORDER BY transactionDate DESC " +
  "LIMIT 20;"
);
```

Can I have this:

```
//Create SQL query
var getAccountsTransactionsStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement(
  "SELECT transactionId, fromAccount, toAccount, transactionDate, transactionAmount, transactionType " +
  "FROM accounttransactions " +
  "WHERE accounttransactions.fromAccount = ? OR accounttransactions.toAccount = ? " +
  "ORDER BY ? DESC " +
  "LIMIT 20;"
);
```

And to invoke it:

```
//Invoke prepared SQL query and return invocation result
function getAccountTransactions1(accountId){
  return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
    preparedStatement : getAccountsTransactionsStatement,
    parameters : [accountId, accountId, transactionDate]
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. This query piece:

   ```
   WHERE accounttransactions.fromAccount = ? OR accounttransactions.toAccount = ?
   ```

   Could be replaced with this:

   ```
   WHERE ? in (accounttransactions.fromAccount, accounttransactions.toAccount)
   ```
2. No you can't. Parameters are values - kind of static stuff - while column names are not. You could probably work around the issue somehow in limited way by using s.t. like this:

   ```
   ORDER BY 
     CASE ?
       WHEN 'transactionDate' THEN transactionDate
       WHEN 'someotherdate' THEN someotherdate
       ELSE DATE '2010-01-01'
     END
   ```

Note however that's a messy construction. Also depending on the type of the database you're using you might want to cast all the columns into one data type i.e. string. so to_char(transactionDate,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mm:ss') might be in order but you need to ensure that the sorting is proper in your case (as number tend to mess stuff up like '2' > '13').

Comment: Thanks @nimdil! Your idea to use the case-when-then in the order by clause works!

Comment: Nice to hear that. Something that I thouht of later on. You could make more flexible set up for ordering with a series of CASE statements - s.t. like: CASE WHEN ? = 'transactionDate' then transactionDate else null end, case when ? = 'someotherdate' THEN someotherdate else null end. This way it will work just as fine and allow you to sort by completely different data types.

Comment: Yes indeed I'm using a similar way currently simply because I want to specify not only the sort column, but each respective sort order too. My setup looks like this: order by case ? when 'transactionDate' then transactionDate end desc, case ? when 'transactionId' then transactionId end asc (and so on).